# Mostrar datos de dos bases mysql distintas en una misma pagina

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen día.
Tengo esa pregunta, tengo dos tablas, con 2 partidos cada una, y quiero mostrar en una misma pagina los 4 partidos que estan en las distintas tablas de la base de datos.
Esto uso para mostrar mi base de datos:

```html
  $sql="SELECT * from dpartidos";
  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
// Lo muestro con un echo y la variable $mostrar['partido1']
```

Y los otros dos partidos que quiero mostrar estan en una tabla que se llama "dpartidos2", y tienen el mismo nombre: "partido3" y "partido4"

Y con este ejemplo:

```html
    $sql="SELECT partido1, partido2
FROM dpartidos
UNION
SELECT partido3, partido4
FROM dpartidos2 ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 0 <= $hora && $hora <= 10) {
    echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12) {
  echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $mostrar['partido1'] . '</h3>';
}

else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 14) {
  echo '<h3>A continuacion: ' . $mostrar['partido1'] . '</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
  echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $mostrar['partido3'] . '</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 16 <= $hora && $hora <= 23) {
    echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
}
}
```

No me pone el partido y me pone dos veces "Estas mirando"

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende bien... ¿por qué tienes dos tablas si ambas almacenan partidos? ¿no es mejor usar una sola tabla?  Aún así, si necesitaras dos tablas, ¿hay una columna identificadora para unir las filas de cada tabla (esa columna debería tener el mismo valor en cada fila coincidente en ambas tablas)? ¿cómo se llama esa columna? ¿si no existe esa columna, por qué no existe?

Comment: No entiendo, respondes mi pregunta con 5 preguntas más, que sentido tiene?
Antes en la misma pregunta me hicieron un choclo, me mandaron otras cosas. Si tienes ganas de ayudar, que no sea de esa manera, porque solo logran confundir y enojar.

Comment: Las preguntas son porque primeramente tu planteamiento no es claro y segundo porque intuyo que estás enfocando mal la solución del problema desde el principio. Ante ciertas situaciones puedes optar por una solución mediocre (sin ánimo de ofender), la cual te obligará a estar aplicando parches hasta un punto en que la situación se hace insostenible; o por una solución más sólida fruto de un punto de partida en el que hay un análisis del problema  más conforme a la realidad. Si respondes a mis preguntas (si quieres) entonces quizá se podría proponer una solución mejor si fuera oportuno.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar UNION para unir los resultados de los dos SELECT en una misma respuesta

```
SELECT *
FROM dpartidos
[WHERE conditions]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dpartido2
[WHERE conditions]
```

ahora como aclaracion, los SELECT deben devolver la misma cantidad de columnas y el tipo de datos de las mismas debe ser igual, supongo q es asi, si no me das mas datos y buscamos otra solucion

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, como se eso de las columnas y datos? Los dos tienen 1 fila, no te entiendo ahí. Eso que me pasaste lo probe y no me funcionó.